# At a wedding, can non-designated witnesses testify later in the court?

Tags: halacha, wedding, edim-witnesses, kiddushin-eirusin

This is a follow-up (a clarification) question on [how-can-there-be-only-2-halachic-witnesses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98443/how-can-there-be-only-2-halachic-witnesses-at-a-large-wedding#98448).

Say, there are ten grown-up, Jewish, frum, non-related men presenting at a Chupah, two of which are chosen to actually witness the Kiddushin and sign the Ketubah following the procedure described in the question above. Those witnesses vanish a week later.

Can any two of the remaining eight testify later in the court for the wedding?

Comment: What would they need to testify about?

Comment: @DoubleAA that he doesn't have to do Yibum with her sister who was married to his brother and she can marry somebody else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not? It would be equivalent to a murderer specifying two witnesses to the murder, and subsequently two other witnesses came to court - would you question their validity?

There is no way to disqualify somebody else's testimony.

As explained [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98443/how-can-there-be-only-two-halachic-witnesses-at-a-large-wedding?noredirect=1&lq=1), the source for the designation of witnesses is the Ritva Kiddushin 43, where this concept is brought as a way of getting around a potential problem of invalid witnesses becoming part of *kat* (set) of witnesses, thereby invalidating all of them.

The whole necessity for this is because for *eidei kiyum* (witnesses necessary to effect the Kiddushin), all present will automatically join into one group [because the 'testimony' is the watching], without specifically designating a different set. In your question, regarding *eidei birur* (for testifying in Beis Din), there is no reason why invalid witnesses would invalidate the Kosher witnesses unless they testified together in Beis Din. [See Rishonim Makkos 9]